# What is the cause of error about react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

`index.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`App.tsx`

```
import { Reset } from "styled-reset";
import { NavBtn } from "./components/nav_btn";
import { Router } from "./router";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Reset />
      <NavBtn />
      <Router />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`nav_btn.tsx`

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { styled } from 'styled-components';

const ProductManageBtn = styled.button`
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
`
const ChangeChargeBtn = styled.button`
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
`
const ProductPurchaseBtn = styled.button`
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
`

export function NavBtn() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <ProductManageBtn>
          <Link to={`/product-manage`}>상품 관리</Link>
        </ProductManageBtn>
        <ChangeChargeBtn>
          <Link to={`/change-charge`}>잔돈 충전</Link>
        </ChangeChargeBtn>
        <ProductPurchaseBtn>
          <Link to={`/product-purchase`}>상품 구매</Link>
        </ProductPurchaseBtn>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

`router.tsx`

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProductManage } from "./pages/product_manage";
import { ChangeCharge } from "./pages/change_charge";
import { ProductPurchase } from "./pages/product_purchase";

export function Router() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/product-manage' element={<ProductManage />} />
        <Route path='/change-charge' element={<ChangeCharge />} /> 
        <Route path='/product-purchase' element={<ProductPurchase />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

The result I want is that when I click the Btn styled-component in nav_btn.tsx, the element component of router.tsx corresponding to the Link appears while the nav_btn component is maintained.
But when I run this, the component doesn't show up, and I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
    at LinkWithRef (index.tsx:528:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement. callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1), The above error occurred in the <Link> component:
    at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38573:7)
    at button
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45518:6)
    at div
    at NavBtn
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries., Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
    at LinkWithRef (index.tsx:528:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1) \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering a `react-router-dom` (RRD) `Link` component ***outside*** the routing context provided by a RRD router component.

Promote the `BrowserRouter` higher in the ReactTree such that it provides the routing context to as much of the app as it necessary. In this case it can simply be moved to the `App` component.

App.tsx

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Reset } from "styled-reset";
import { NavBtn } from "./components/nav_btn";
import { AppRoutes } from "./router";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> // <-- provides routing context
      <Reset />
      <NavBtn />    // <-- consumes routing context
      <AppRoutes /> // <-- consumes routing context
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

router.tsx

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProductManage } from "./pages/product_manage";
import { ChangeCharge } from "./pages/change_charge";
import { ProductPurchase } from "./pages/product_purchase";

export function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/product-manage' element={<ProductManage />} />
      <Route path='/change-charge' element={<ChangeCharge />} /> 
      <Route path='/product-purchase' element={<ProductPurchase />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: BrowserRouter
It is a parent component that contains other components in React Router,
It saves the current location and synchronizes the UI and URL using the html5 history api.
My code is outside BrowserRouter
Is the error caused by using the Link component, a sub-component of BrowserRouter?

Comment: @pocari Yes, the issue was that the code was rendering a `Link` outside the `BrowserRouter` component.